# Is it true that the sum of a set of ordered positive numbers is always greater than or equal to the max of the values times its index?

Tags: inequality

Given a set of positive real numbers $\left \{x_{1},...,x_{R} \right \}$ ordered such that $x_{1} \geq x_{2} \geq ... \geq x_{|R|}$, is it true that
$$ \sum_{i\in \left \{1,..., R\right \}}x_{i} \geq \max_{i\in \left \{1,..., R\right \}}\left ( ix_{i} \right ) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because for every $i$, there are at least $i$ elements in the sum that are greater than or equal to $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{j\in \left \{1,..., R\right \}}x_{j} \geq \sum_{j\in \left \{1,..., i\right \}}x_{j} \geq \sum_{j\in \left \{1,..., i\right \}}x_{i} = i x_i$ (the last inequality taking place because of the ordering of the $x_j$'s and the first by their positivity) for all $i$ so that $\sum_{j\in \left \{1,..., R\right \}}x_{j} \geq \max_{i\in \left \{1,..., R\right \}}\left ( ix_{i} \right )$